# unable to display chinese character using PHP

Tags: php

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM customers";

if ($conn_id=odbc_connect("testconn","user1","user1")){
  echo "connected to DSN: $dsn <br>";

  if($result=odbc_do($conn_id, $sql)){
  }
}
```

I have a database which is utf-8,I am using the below PHP code,it is not displaying the Chinese character.I have tried with other ODBC clients,connecting to same odbc datasource and they are able to display Chinese character.I have tried suggestion mentioned here But still I am not able to display Chinese character

Comment: Is your web page set to display UTF-8? What kind of DB?

Comment: I recommend you [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) and go on from there. Much more useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a php problem.
add this in the head tag of your HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: It can be PHP header, database connection, database-tables, etc... Could be a number of things, most likely something with PHP or the database.